# Saving custom class data into core data with swift

Tags: arrays, swift, class, core-data

I am trying to implement saving decks of flash cards into core data, storing individual decks into core data. The decks are custom class with a name and and array of custom class cards, cards just have term and definition. But I keep getting error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'flashcard_.Cards' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
```

error when I press the addCardPressed, I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
2019-01-05 18:00:55.196270-0600 flashcard![35177:1718243] [error] error:  Failed to load model named flashPrototype
CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named flashPrototype
2019-01-05 18:00:55.197121-0600 flashcard![35177:1718243] [error] error: No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'flashcard_.Cards' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?
CoreData: error: No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'flashcard_.Cards' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?
2019-01-05 18:00:55.197499-0600 flashcard![35177:1718243] [error] error: +[flashcard_.Cards entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
CoreData: error: +[flashcard_.Cards entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
2019-01-05 18:00:55.341425-0600 flashcard![35177:1718243] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'flashcard_.Cards' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
```

[core data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k1CN.png)

@IBAction func addCardPressed(_ sender: Any) {

```
    if(termInput.text != "type term here..." && definitionInput.text != "type definition here..." && termInput.text != "" && definitionInput.text != ""){

        let cardToAdd = Cards(context: context)
            cardToAdd.term = termInput.text
            cardToAdd.definition = definitionInput.text
            cardArray.append(cardToAdd)
    }
}

@IBAction func studyPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if(deckNameInput.text != "" && deckNameInput.text != "ex: physchology 101"){

        let deck = Decks(context: context)
        deck.cards = cardArray
        deck.name = deckNameInput.text

        ad.saveContext()
    }
```

Comment: Everything else seems fine, but you need to load the managedObjectModel. In other words, try to link the context to the model via entity.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Load model first before using the custom core data class